# LeafletJS Tooltip offset depending on properties.name

Tags: javascript, leaflet, tooltip

I've created a layer with JSON for a polygon and trying to add permanent tooltips. The issue is that because of the way the polygon works, the tooltip goes to the center. This is fine for most of the labels but there is just one that is in a really awkward place. I've written the code below to offset just that one tooltip, but instead it is changing ALL the tooltips to have the name "Ross Sea" and offsetting them all.. What am I doing wrong?

```
var seaLayer = L.geoJson(seaRegions, {
       style: function(feature) {
           return feature.properties.style
       },
       onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        if (feature.properties.name = "Ross Sea") {
                    layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.name, {className: "newContent", permanent: true, direction:"center", offset: L.point({x: -80, y: 80}) }); 
        } else {
            layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.name, {className: "newContent", permanent: true, direction:"center"}); 
        }
       }
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `==` instead `=`. You init the value `Ross Sea` in the if to all features.

Change to:

```
if (feature.properties.name == "Ross Sea") {
                    layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.name, {className: "newContent", permanent: true, direction:"center", offset: L.point({x: -80, y: 80}) }); 
        } else {
            layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.name, {className: "newContent", permanent: true, direction:"center"}); 
        }
```

Comment: Knew it would be something simple. Thank you